# Возвращение результата функции

Tags: python-3.x, pascal

Задача: Найти произведение первых n членов такой последовательности, что каждый следующий ее член больше предыдущего на 2.

Что не так в коде?

```
def F(n):
    def F2(x, k, n):
        if k == n:
            return x
        else:
            return x * F2(x + 2, k + 1, n)
    return F2(1, 1, n)

for i in range(11):
    print('{0}\n'.format(F(i)))
```

Выдает:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "python", line 10, in 
      File "python", line 7, in F
      File "python", line 6, in F2
      File "python", line 6, in F2
      File "python", line 6, in F2
      [Previous line repeated 991 more times]
      File "python", line 3, in F2
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Аналогичный код:

```
function F(n: integer): integer;
  function F2(x, k, n: integer): integer;
  begin
    if k = n then Result := x else Result := x * F2(x + 2, k + 1, n);
  end;

begin
  Result := F2(1, 1, n);
end;

begin
  for var i := 1 to 10 do
    Writeln(F(i));
end.
```

Comment: Первый вызов у вас F(i) c i = 0